# Knowing customer context in AWS API Gateway with API Key

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, api-key

I am setting up API Gateway for my lambda function and use Proxy integration. I also create usage plans & API Keys for this API and share the API keys k1 & k2, with two customers c1 & c2.

When customer makes call with key k2, is there a way to find from my lambda function that the request is made by c2?

I have a java handler implementing `RequestHandler<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent>`

but unfortunately I am not finding customer context in `APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not get customer context in the event wth `API keys`. API keys can be shared across multiple `usage plans` for different APIs. So they cannot be tied to any one API deployment. If you want to do this, you will manage it on your own (e.g. restrict 1 API to 1 customer, API key mapping to customer).

I think one reason AWS does not provide this is because `API keys` are meant purely for `usage plans`. Any sort of authentication/authorization (where user identification is important) needs to be done using other techniques like `IAM`, `Cognito user pools` or `custom authorizer`. Please see [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html#api-gateway-create-usage-plans).

> To include API methods in a usage plan, you must configure individual API methods to require an API key. For user authentication and authorization, don't use API keys. Use an IAM role, a Lambda authorizer, or an Amazon Cognito user pool.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the API key to HTTP header at Method Request and Integration Request so that Lambda receives the API Key provided and then a function in Lambda selects the code to be run or print user number according to the API key that was read.

[image]

Comment: the post said, api key 1 and key 2 is set already, why you need bothering with creating new username and password?

Comment: Yes, I think we do not need username/password here. I do get API key value in the lambda - but then I don't think of a way to get Customer name or API Key name using API key value

Comment: It's just an illustration of the API Gateway flow from Integration Request to Lambda. With the API key you won't need password and username, of course.